# What are the differences between the original and the re-cut versions of Psycho-Pass?

Tags: psycho-pass

I know that the original show has 22 episodes and the re-cut version has 11 one hour long episodes. However, I want to know if there are any major differences. What are the differences between the 2012 version and the 2014 version of Psycho-Pass? Did they add new scenes or information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The new edit version of Psycho-Pass has:

- Reanimated Opening and Ending themes
- Additional minor scenes (for example in episode 1 there are two new soliloquies not seen in the original). These tend to be placed midway during the episodes to allow for a better transition between the two old episodes.
- Redone animation of particular scenes (and some additional CGI in places)
- Some music changes in scenes

There's nothing substantially different in the new edit version, so if you have seen the original there's not a huge benefit in watching this version and you should still be able to watch the sequel Psycho-Pass 2 in Fall 2014 without worries.