# Psycho Pass Episode / Special Order

Tags: psycho-pass

I just watched season 1 (episodes 1-22) of Psycho Pass on Netflix and now I want to watch the rest.

On the Funimation site there is:

- Episodes 1-22 (Season 1)
- Specials 1-11
- Episodes 23-33 (Season 2)
- Also there is the recently released movie.

I haven't started any of the specials or season 2 yet; I don't want to accidentally watch something out of order and spoil it. My question is: Where do the specials fit into the series? Between the two seasons? Side stories? Prequel? After season 2? When should I watch them?

The episode lists I've found seem to leave out the specials so I'm not sure how they fit in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've watched the first season, you should skip the specials and proceed directly to the second season. After that, watch the movie (when it's available).

The "specials" (usually called "Psycho Pass: New Edit" or "Psycho Pass: Extended Edition", I think) are a re-cut/updated version of season 1, [with only minor changes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/14021/1908). The reason there are only 11 of them is that they're double-length. If you were starting from nothing, it would have been better to watch the "specials" and then season 2, but since you've already seen season 1, I don't think there's enough new content to warrant watching the re-cut version before moving on to season 2.

That said, if you ever find yourself wanting to rewatch the first season of Psycho Pass, I would recommend watching the "specials" instead of the original version of season 1.

Answer (score 2):

The chronological order to watch Psycho Pass would be

1. Psycho Pass Season 1.
2. Psycho Pass: The Movie (movie)
3. Psycho Pass Season 2.
4. Psycho Pass: Sinners of System Case.1-3 (movies)
5. Psycho Pass Season 3.
6. Psycho Pass 3: First Inspector (movie)