# Order of watching psycho pass?

Tags: psycho-pass

Can someone provide the correct order of watching the ova's and movies with the seasons

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Psycho Pass Episode / Special Order](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18840/psycho-pass-episode-special-order)

Answer (score 0):

1. Season 1
2. Season 2
3. Psycho-Pass: The Movie (2015)
4. Sinners of the System (2019)
5. Season 3
6. Psycho-Pass: First Inspector (2020)

[Source.](https://beekian.wordpress.com/2020/03/29/psycho-pass-watch-order/)